# How do I make a UIView "scrollable" in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` that will eventually contain about 2 screens worth of information. I want to give the user the ability to scroll down via flicking (just standard flicking like in Safari).
How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Place your `UIView` inside a `UIScrollView`.  Apple has some good example code for this on their developer pages.